# ImportError: No module named libsvm in Python 3

Tags: python, pip, libsvm

```
from libsvm import svmutil
ImportError: No module named libsvm
```

I have the module `libsvm` installed. Because when I run `pip3 install libsvm`, I see this:

`Requirement already satisfied: libsvm in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.23.0.4)`

So what's causing the error?

Comment: You're likely not running the script and the `pip3` command in the same virtual environment.

Comment: You probably have multiple Pythons installed.  This is often a problem on MacOS. If you do `python -V, what does it say?

Comment: @TimRoberts Python 2.7.18

Comment: do you have another file in the same directory called libsvm.py?

Comment: @bn_ln I do not

Comment: And do you see the problem?  You used `pip3`, which installed the package in Python 3, but when you type `python xxx.py`, you are getting Python 2.  Try typing `python3` instead of `python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make sure you are using the same python version, when you install the library and you run it. fyi, pip3 is for python 3.
2. my suggestion is create new virtual environment and activate then install all library that needed, then run your app from there.

Comment: What do you mean by virtual environment? Do you mean my terminal on MacOS?

Comment: virtual environment is an  isolated environment from OS. What ever you install there will not affect to your main python environment / OS. if you are not in virtual env, meaning you are using the operationg system environment. 
to create virtual env : python -m venv my_venv, to activate it : . my_venv/bin/activate

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings, it may solve the problem:

0- Run your code with Python version 3 and above. (`python3 yourFile.py` in the terminal)

1- `pip3 install libsvm`

2- `pip install -U libsvm-official`

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting `Exception: LIBSVM library not found.` now?

Comment: try to run `make` in the directory of the library (probably `libsvm-3`)

Comment: @Adrian, you get the Error because your default python is version 2, and you installed libsvm in python version 3. pip3 is for python3, everything you install using pip3, it will be listed in python 3, as your comment above, your default python is version 2

Comment: @HenroSutrisnoTanjung, I've changed the default python to version 3 (i.e., if I run `python --version`, now I have `Python 3.10.7` but I still have the same error with `libsvm` for some reason

Comment: how do you run your file .py, have you tried this command : python3 your_file.py

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I'm running my .py